# Java program for factorial incorrect output

Tags: java, eclipse, vbscript, factorial

I am executing the below piece of Java code in Eclipse IDE.

```java
public class Programs {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int i, num, n;
        n = 6;
        // num=n-1;
        for (i = 1; i <= n - 1; i++) {
            n = n * i;
        }
        System.out.println("Factorial of the declared number is" + " " + n);
    }

}
```

It shows the output as -1420957696. The code works fine if I uncomment and use the "num" variable in the for loop. I think for every iteration the value of `n` changes gradually incredibly as compared to value of `i`. The same code works fine in VBScript (see below). Can anyone explain the difference?

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim  i, num
num = InputBox("enter a number")
For i=1 To num-1
    num = num * i
Next
MsgBox "The factorial of entered number is: " & num, 3, "Program for factorial"
```

Answer (score 6):

**Java:**

`n` is going to get rather big cf. `i`.

Therefore `i <= n - 1` will always be `true`, until your `n` overflows and wraps around to a negative.

One fix would be to use `num` to hold the original value of `n`, and use `i <= num - 1` as the stopping condition.

---

**VBScript:**

In the various basics (E.g. VBScript, VBA), `num-1` is effectively computed at the start of the loop, and further adjustment to `num` have no effect on the stopping condition.  You can see this explicitly by running

```vb
Dim j
Dim i

j = 10
For i = 1 To j
    WScript.Echo i
    j = 1 'has no effect on the stopping condition.
Next
```

Answer (score 5):

every iteration in the forloop i<=n-1 is checked. Because n is increased all the time, the for loop will run until n reaches the highest possible number of INTEGER and becomes negative.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

you are not storing previous multiplication in another variable and your ***n***  is always increasing so the condition in **for** for **i** changes every iteration.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the above answers evaluation of the condition causes the exception. What you can do is keep a separate variable to check the condition in the loop like this.

```
int i,fact=1;  
  int number=5;//Number to calculate factorial    
  for(i=1;i<=number;i++){    
      fact=fact*i;    
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that's the difference between vbscript and Java :)

Answer (score 2):

it comes down to when numbers are read compared to when they are set:

```
n = 6;
for (i = 1; i <= n - 1; i++) {
    n = n * i;
}
```

What java will do is:
Set `i = 1`, do the check `i <= n-1` (1 <= 5) then execute the code in the braces, then increment i (`i++`).
Then this is repeated:
i is now equal to 2, do the check `i <= n-1` (2 <= 4) n has changed in the last iteration so the check will use the new value. so on the next iteration `n = 12`.

This causes `n` to grow faster than `i` so when the capacity of an integer is exceeded causing `n` to go negative the loop condition resolves to false.

The answer is to not modify the value in your loop condition inside the loop.

```
n = 6;
num = n - 1;
for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    n = n * i;
}
```

The way the loop is working for VB is by calculating the numbers for the beginning and end of the loop when it is started, meaning that `num` was only read once.

Answer (score 1):

You are not storing previous multiplication in another variable and your `n` is always increasing so the condition in for  `i` changes every iteration.
Instead you can have separate variable to hold your `factorial`.

```
class FactorialExample{  
 public static void main(String args[]){  
  int i,fact=1;  
  int number=5;//It is the number to calculate factorial    
  for(i=1;i<=number;i++){    
      fact=fact*i;    
  }    
  System.out.println("Factorial of "+number+" is: "+fact);    
 }  
}
```

Hope that Helps.